# Ajax Push Engine does not work only in FF :(

Tags: ajax, firefox, push, ape

When I launch the APE test I get this error on FF:

> Running test : Initializing APE Client
>
> Can't load APE JSF

In IE and Chrome everything work fine...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. I guess you're trying to make APE work on your local machine. Firefox has special restrictions on TLDs to avoid XSS scripting. I solved this problem by renaming my local domain from **`localdomain`** to **`localdomain.local`**. So you need to add the following to your /etc/hosts (assuming you're working on *nix platform):

```
127.0.0.1 localdomain.local
127.0.0.1 0.localdomain.local
127.0.0.1 1.localdomain.local
127.0.0.1 2.localdomain.local
127.0.0.1 3.localdomain.local
127.0.0.1 4.localdomain.local
127.0.0.1 5.localdomain.local
127.0.0.1 6.localdomain.local
127.0.0.1 7.localdomain.local
127.0.0.1 8.localdomain.local
127.0.0.1 9.localdomain.local
```

You should also change your vhost and Demos/config.js config. Assuming you have APE JSF installed on wwwroot/ape/APE_JSF, you can now access the config check at the following url:

```
http://localdomain.local/ape/APE_JSF/Tools/Check/index.html
```

*Source:* http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat